# Pig right join relations with multiple relations on different fields

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have 3 relations A,B,C

```
A(Ka1,Ka2,Ka3)
B(Kb1,Kb2)
C(Kc1,Kc2)
```

I want to join like this

```
joined_data = JOIN B by Kb1 RIGHT, A by Ka2;
joined_data = JOIN C by Kb2 RIGHT, joined_data by Ka3;
```

So that I end up with an output like this

```
joined_data(Ka1,Ka3,Ka2,Kb2,Kc2)
```

Is there a better / more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Ho big are the relations? Can any of the relations fit in memory?

Comment: only 1 can be fit in memory(Say C), the others are massive